# Не получается запустить виртуальную машину в Virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, hyper-v

Не получается запустить виртуалку в virtualbox.
- В UEFI параметр VT-d включён.
- Служба Hyper-V работает.
- Процессор виртуализацию поддерживает.
- Windows 10.
Если выполнить команду systeminfo: *Требования Hyper-V:               Обнаружена низкоуровневая оболочка. Функции, необходимые для Hyper-V, отображены не будут.*
Если поставить виртуалку через Vagrant, при запуске виртуалки машина падает в BSOD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нашёл решение проблемы. Как я понял для безопасности винда как бы сама запускается в вируталке, поэтому выдаёт такое сообщение. Эта функция называется Credential Guard.

Для того чтобы отключить эту фишку нужно:
Программы и компоненты -> Включение или отключение компонентов Windows ->  Hyper-V -> Платформа Hyper-V -> Низкоуровневая оболочка Hyper-V (убрать галку)

Comment: Всем привет, у меня таже проблема и ваш вариант не помог. Я пытаюсь запустить эмулятор Android для создания мобильный приложений на Xamarin.

Comment: "systeminfo" побывал выполнять?

Comment: Аналогично, в BIOS включено, процессор поддреживает, но пишет сообщение как в вопросе при вызове systeminfo

Comment: Если кто знает как в Windows вообще сделать все(хоть какие нибудь) проверки по виртуализации. Ситуация такая же как описал @falko.

UPD CPU-Z показывает что инструкций VT-x нет.

Comment: `bcdedit /enum` показывает `hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto`, но это мало что даёт о текущем положении дел

Comment: `hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto` оказывается что это значит `On`, "как не явно... ", вообщем сделал `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`, перезагрузился и в CPU-Z появились инструкции VT-x, и VirtualBox взлетел. А вот Docker упал... беда `system info` стал выдавать: `Требования Hyper-V:               Расширения режима мониторинга виртуальной машины: Да
Виртуализация включена во встроенном ПО: Да
Преобразование адресов второго уровня: Да
Доступно предотвращение выполнения данных: Да` - извините за форматирование, комменты не позволяют..

Comment: Как я понял Docker for Windows работает с Hyper-V, а если у тебя VirtualBox, то нужно использовать Docker Toolbox https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases какой-то ужос..

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел решение данной проблемы. Нужно перевести `hypervisorlaunchtype Auto` в положение `Off` (например, с помощью команды `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`). После данной манипуляции Hyper-V проходит проверку.

Comment: подскажите, где посмотреть/изменить значение hypervisorlaunchtype, о котором Вы пишете?

Comment: @YakovL Откройте командную строку Windows (CMD) и выполните команду: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`